# Ploting pandas panel across one dimension

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panel of data and I want to slice the cude of data to plot it.

Eg. A slice on the minor dimension. The data is

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 71 (items) x 192 (major) x 19 (minor)
Items: gain to gain_delta
Major axis: AFG to ZWE
Minor axis: ISO3 to 2011
```

So If I want  to plot this slice:

```
scores.ix[['gain'],['ESP'],2:21]
```

gives

```
<bound method Panel.to_frame of <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1 (items) x 1 (major) x 17 (minor)
Items: gain to gain
Major axis: ESP to ESP
Minor axis: 1995 to 2011>
```

but these all give errors:

```
scores.ix[['gain'],['ESP'],2:21].plot()

scores.ix[['gain'],['ESP'],2:21].to_frame.plot()

a=scores.ix[['gain'],['ESP'],2:21]
plot(a)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can plot a panel.

To extract the Series (and plot) from the panel you can use `ix` with the following syntax:

```
scores.ix['gain', 'ESP', 2:21].plot()
```